# Class methods: describe "#my_class_method" or describe "#self.my_class_method"?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I try to have best-practice-conforming RSpec tests, and I know that when testing an instance method, one can do

```
describe "#my_instance_method" do ... end
```

But what about class methods? Should I add a `self.` to it in the description string?

```
describe "#self.my_class_method" do ... end
```

Thanks for your opinion!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From "[How to name RSpec describe blocks for methods](http://grosser.it/2010/06/18/how-to-name-rspec-describe-blocks-for-methods/)":

- use pound `#method` for instance methods
- use dot `.method` for class methods

In your example:

```
describe "#my_instance_method" do
  # ...
end
describe ".my_class_method" do 
  # ...
end
```

A few examples from rspec-core: [for class method](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/e961660aa0a1224906559ae88375cf5a4e268a11/spec/rspec/core_spec.rb#L106-L110), [for instance method](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/3f8526819b3d6f2328521cd0391e7064458758e4/spec/rspec/core/example_spec.rb#L783-L793)

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find more information about such best practices?

Comment: The presentation this comes from is very good: http://pure-rspec-rubynation.heroku.com/ and of course [The RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book)

Comment: 10 yrs later but still.. In case anyone is looking on how to write better specs, you should check out these: https://relishapp.com/rspec/ https://www.betterspecs.org/

Comment: @BinaryButterfly unfortunately, relishapp is no longer available. There's a long story behind that and its really sad. However, I was not aware of betterspecs. Thank you, I'll start using this site for insight on RSpec.

Comment: Apparently, the docs from Relish were migrated over to https://rspec.info/documentation now